# Creating topic on pubsub emulator

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

I started to use the pubsub emulator to test my basic implementations and ran into an issue while trying to create a new topic.

My emulator listens on localhost:8085 and if i create the topic via the api

```
PUT http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/testproject/topics/test
```

everything works fine and the topic gets created.
But if i run the following snippet nothing works as intended and no topic gets created:

```
    TopicName topicName = TopicName.create("testproject", "test");
    ChannelProvider channelProvider =
            TopicAdminSettings.defaultChannelProviderBuilder()
                .setEndpoint("localhost:8085")
                .setCredentialsProvider(
                        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(NoCredentials.getInstance()))
                .build();
    TopicAdminClient topicClient = TopicAdminClient.create(
            TopicAdminSettings.defaultBuilder().setChannelProvider(channelProvider).build());
        topicClient.createTopic(topicName);
```

while running this the emulator logs

```
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Unknown request URI: /bad-request
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:47 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Unknown request URI: /bad-request

...    

[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:49 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[pubsub] Apr 27, 2017 1:10:49 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[pubsub] INFORMATION: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
```

Am i missing something on my ChannelProvider? Or didn't I configure my TopicAdminClient correctly? I don't see whats wrong since i used 
[this as reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/TESTING.md#testing-code-that-uses-pubsub).

Maybe someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Channels used to communicate with the emulator need to set the `negotiationType` property to `NegotiationType.PLAINTEXT`. That means you need to create a custom `ChannelProvider`. Something like the following should work:

```
public class PlainTextChannelProvider implements ChannelProvider {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldAutoClose() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean needsExecutor() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public ManagedChannel getChannel() throws IOException {
    return NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8085)
      .negotiationType(NegotiationType.PLAINTEXT)
      .build();
  }

  @Override
  public ManagedChannel getChannel(Executor executor) throws IOException {
    return getChannel();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for creating Topics and publishing Messages. Do i have to implement something similar for the Subscriber.Listener aswell? I set the same channelProvider for the Subscriber but when calling subscriber.stopAsync(), it always throws an java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException and (it seems randomly) does or doesn't pull messages, am i missing something here?

Comment: You will need to use the same sort of ChannelProvider for your Subscriber, too, yes. It is hard to say what is causing the RejectedExecutionException. I don't think that is a problem specific to the Subscriber or emulator but might be specific to your code around subscribing, any Executors you use, or the lifetime of objects in your app.

Comment: i opened another question so i can give a more detailed description [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786716/subscriber-stopasync-results-in-rejectedexecutionexception)

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn, I run into the same exception, the solution you provide is a bit outdated. It now needs a TransportChannelProvider. Is the fix this applicable?

Answer (score 3):

This post is a little old, hope this serves as an update.

The [code snippet](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#pubsub-emulator-java) from [Testing apps locally with the emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) also works. The full snippet is on GitHub if you follow the "View on GitHub" link on the linked page.

```java
String hostport = System.getenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build();
try {
  TransportChannelProvider channelProvider =
      FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel));
  CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create();

  TopicAdminClient topicClient =
      TopicAdminClient.create(
          TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
              .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
              .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
              .build());
  try {
      response = topicClient.createTopic(topicName);
      System.out.printf("Topic %s created.\n", response);
  } catch (ApiException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getStatusCode().getCode());
      System.out.println(e.isRetryable());
      System.out.println("No topic was created.");
  }

} finally {
  channel.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Any reason why SSL/TLS support is not added?