# Subscriber.stopAsync() results in RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

My code is basically following the official tutorials and the main purpose is to collect all messages from one subscription (Constants.UNFINISHEDSUBID) and republish them on another. But currently I'm facing a problem, that i can't solve. In my implementation calling subscriber.stopAsync() results in the following exception:

```
Mai 04, 2017 4:59:25 PM com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture executeListener
SCHWERWIEGEND: RuntimeException while executing runnable com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6@6e13e898 with executor java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedScheduledExecutorService@2f3c6ac4
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@60d40af2 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@d55b6e[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 320]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:613)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.set(ClientCalls.java:458)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:437)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:428)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:76)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:514)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:431)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also noticed that kind of randomly, sometimes all messages and sometimes just a few or not a single one get collected. Is calling subscriber.stopAsync() not the correct way?

My current implementation:

```
protected void pullUnfinished() throws Exception {
    List<PubsubMessage> jobsToRepublish = new ArrayList<>();
    SubscriptionName subscription =
            SubscriptionName.create(Constants.PROJECTID, Constants.UNFINISHEDSUBID);

    MessageReceiver receiver = new MessageReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
            synchronized(jobsToRepublish){
                jobsToRepublish.add(message);
            }
            String unfinishedJob = message.getData().toStringUtf8();
            LOG.info("got message: {}", unfinishedJob);
            consumer.ack();
        }
    };

    Subscriber subscriber = null;
    try {
        ChannelProvider channelProvider = new PlainTextChannelProvider();
        subscriber = Subscriber.defaultBuilder(subscription, receiver)
                               .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                               .build();
        subscriber.addListener(new Subscriber.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void failed(Subscriber.State from, Throwable failure) {
                System.err.println(failure);
            }
        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
        subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
        Thread.sleep(60000);
    } finally {
        if (subscriber != null) {
            subscriber.stopAsync(); //Causes the exception
        }
    }
    publishJobs(jobsToRepublish);
}

public class PlainTextChannelProvider implements ChannelProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldAutoClose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsExecutor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

      @Override
      public ManagedChannel getChannel() throws IOException {
        return NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8085)
          .negotiationType(NegotiationType.PLAINTEXT)
          .build();
      }

      @Override
      public ManagedChannel getChannel(Executor executor) throws IOException {
        return getChannel();
      } 
}
```

Comment: Try adding a signal to stop. See sample code in [`startSync`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.4/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/spi/v1/Subscriber.html#stopAsync--) to see how it is implemented. Also as stated in this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19006386/5995040), RejectedExecutionException is caused by the queue is full and you cannot add any more threads or the ThreadPool has been shutdown. Check you code implementation. Hope this helps.

Comment: tried this already, doesn't change anything for me I'm still getting the same rejectedExecutionException. I tried these [snippets](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/d476ef7904467233e83168b8d1f5a934a0aae711/google-cloud-examples/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/snippets/ITPubSubSnippets.java) and still got the exception, but it seems like im receiving the messages eventhough running into the exception 
irritates me, any other ideas?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with subscriber.stopAsync(); with the latest library, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when running similar code from a JUnit test, and found this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003430/what-are-the-possible-reason-for-a-java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexcepti) on multithreading in general, suggesting that a ThreadPool is closed while Listeners are still referring to it. I also looked into the code of [Subscriber.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java) on GitHub, and found an example for receiving a number of messages in the JavaDoc on startAsync(), suggesting to wait for termination of stopAsync().

Try changing

```
subscriber.stopAsync();
```

to

```
subscriber.stopAsync().awaitTerminated();
```

Worked for me.