# Firestore emulator outputs dozens of the same info message per second

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a firebase firestore and authentication emulator, and in the console that appears when I run it, the following info message appears maybe 20-50 times every second:

```
Nov 30, 2022 1:55:13 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
Nov 30, 2022 1:55:13 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
Nov 30, 2022 1:55:13 AM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
```

Does anyone know why this happens? Everything seems to be working completely fine, so I didn't really notice it until now, and there doesn't seem to be that much information on it

Comment: Jeffmagma, do Let me know if the recommendations below were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The message information in the firebase debug log  looks like there is a Pub/Sub service, where the Pub/Sub server may be able to send messages as a HTTP request to the subscriber application and  the HTTP message reaches the subscriber application, but there is an error code “Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.” when receiving the acknowledgement message.You can try the workaround mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137292/local-pubsub-emulator-wont-work-with-dataflow).

Please read this [official document](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#using_the_emulator) for the emulator pubsub topic  and verify if all the steps were taken during the setup and configurations.
One more possible cause could  be that the `PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST` environment variable is not set to “localhost:8085”. To set the environment variable again, use [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#env).
Also If you are using channel, you may need to set negotiation type like this: NegotiationType.PLAINTEXT , as per a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657112/creating-topic-on-pubsub-emulator) mentioned here.